# android emulator won't start on ubuntu 12.04 after when run from ssh

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, ubuntu-12.04

I built the android source code based on the http://source.android.com/source/building.html on Ubuntu 12.04 and when I run the emulator I'm getting the error and emulator won't start:

```
WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 
         is not supported!  This is an application bug!
X Error of failed request:  GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  146 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Any idea how can I fix that?

I need to mention that I connect to the machine with SSH. When I connect from an Ubuntu machine and run, it works fine but when I connect to it with my macbook machine through the SSH and try to run it gives me above error.

BR,
Ramin

Comment: Could you please post your configuration (RAM, CPU ...) ? Here is a link that could interest you : http://www.rtsoft.com/forums/showthread.php?2927-pbuffers-on-intel-cards-no-luck

Comment: 8 processors with below config: 
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 26
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
stepping : 5
microcode : 0x11
cpu MHz  : 2260.570
cache size : 8192 KB
fpu  : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp  : yes
flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm ida dts
bogomips : 4521.14

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers    
Mem:          7983       5998       1985          0        260      
-/+ buffers/cache:       3548       4435
Swap:        11641        683      10958

Comment: @FurnitureSell better to edit your question to provide this info rather than comments

Comment: can you run glxgears?  if not try enabling dri

Answer (score 10):

Found out about a work around yesterday.

The issue seems to be with android-sdks/tools/emulator, while emulator-**arm** seems to work fine.

To test cd to the android-sdks/tools directory and type:
`emulator-arm -avd your_avd`

Looks like this forces the emulator to use the software renderer instead of OpenGL, but for me (using NX) it worked.

I found the work around here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+question/203681

Answer (score 2):

This error probably indicates the app requires direct access to the screen. Using nx rather than X over SSH may avoid the problem. Look if there is a run time option on the emulator too.

Answer (score 0):

The MacOSX X server is complaining about misuse of some GL functions, which may be caused by flaws on either side. When using Ubuntu as client, the X environment obviously matches well.

Maybe you should try to run the emulator on the local display, and view it by VNC or something similiar. If the SSH connection is critical, you could tunnel VNC trough SSH, some VNC clients  directly offer that option.