# Android emulator not working on ubuntu

Tags: android

I am a newbie android learner. I have downloaded the adt bundle from the developer's site,
but I am running into problems when I run the android emulator. I have an x86-64 architecture with Ubuntu 12.04. After booting the avd, when I run the android application, it gives the following error:

```
[2013-09-16 18:53:50 - Emulator] X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
[2013-09-16 18:53:50 - Emulator]   Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
[2013-09-16 18:53:50 - Emulator]   Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
[2013-09-16 18:53:50 - Emulator]   Serial number of failed request:  12
[2013-09-16 18:53:50 - Emulator]   Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is "the android application" you refer to?

Comment: Looks like an X11 issue.  I doubt the emulator opens up at all.

Comment: There is a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998146/android-emulator-wont-start-on-ubuntu-12-04-after-when-run-from-ssh?rq=1 ... Plus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17133773/android-emulator-can-not-start-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805725/android-emulator-can-not-start-in-ubuntu-12-04-64bit-x-error-of-failed-request?rq=1

Comment: @RafaelT The android application is the default "Hello World" program

Comment: Have you tried to run the Emulator without starting an application on it?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. The link suggested above [android emulator won't start on ubuntu 12.04 after when run from ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998146/android-emulator-wont-start-on-ubuntu-12-04-after-when-run-from-ssh?rq=1) included the tip to run, from the terminal, this:

```
emulator-arm -avd your_avd
```

and it did launch the emulator.

A quick, very dirty way to make Eclipse use emulator-arm instead of emulator when launching projects, was just to rename emulator-arm as emulator in the adt-bundle/sdk/tools folder.

It works for me.

If anyone has a better idea, (i.e. how to make the generic emulator work on Ubuntu 12.04 in the first place, or how to configure eclipse so that it uses emulator-arm instead of emulator in order to launch an avd), please let us know.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply:) i didn't have the graphics library installed on my system. I installed it and the android emulator is working fine now.